# Buffer with dissolve - Geopandas - unary_union multipolygon

Tags: python, dissolve, geopandas, multipart

I am trying to buffer points which are quite close together, and then dissolve the overlapping buffer polygons into larger polygons. After doing the buffer is where I have the issue. I have tried using dissolve('geometry') but that gives this error.

```
KeyError: 'geometry'
```

I think the proper way to do this is using unary_union but my output is a multipolygon and I cant use it.

```
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(SELECT)
gdf2b = gdf2.buffer(gridDist)
gdfu = gdf2b.unary_union
gdfu.plot()

AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Or if I try to send the unary_union to a file

```
gpd.GeoSeries.to_file(gdf3u, BUFF1, driver="ESRI Shapefile")

AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'index'
```

So my question is how can I either dissolve these polygons based on their self intersecting geometry and have the result be a geodataframe or a geoseries?
Or how can I transform the multipolygon I have from into a geodataframe?

[image: Plot of buffered points]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the geometry into a new GeoDataFrame, that's what has the `.plot()` method.

```
new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=gdf2.crs, geometry=[gdfu])
new.plot()
```

then you can write out the `new` object

```
new.to_file('path/to/file')
```

Comment: Thanks So Much! I know this is simple but I couldnt find how to make a geodataframe from geometry in the geopandas documentation! It should be right up there with geodataframe.from_file